# What is the proper way to use pyinstaller on Mac?

Tags: python, pyinstaller, python-standalone

i know many articles about pyinstaller for mac has been written, but i still can't solve my problem after trying lots of them.

I have built a simple python app with Tkinker, which has a super small sqlite file with it. The app is here, https://github.com/yts61/bookstore_app.git

Now i am packing it with pyinstaller, in the hope to make one standalone app file which i can share around. However, no matter which one i tried:

```
pyinstaller --windowed  --onefile app.py

pyinstaller --onefile app.py

pyinstaller -F app.py,

pyinstaller -w app.py, etc
```

i even tried the solution suggested by this article, https://jacob-brown.github.io/2019-09-10-pyinstaller/, skipped "onefile", and used only "-w", then ran the following py file,

```
python TCLChanger.py
```

But still the file in the list folder won't run.

would anyone please suggest me the proper way to use pyinstaller?

Comment: I have put the app in GitHub, feel free to check it out, please if anyone succeeds in turning it into a standalone app, please let me know how.

Comment: Are you still having problems with this? I create Tkinker, PySimpleGUI, and KIVY apps all the time and use PyInstaller. Before I answer it I would like to clarify what you are asking. When you say you "hope to make one standalone app file" Are you stating one file for Mac? Or a combination of files that will work on all operating systems?