# What is the proper way to turn a python app into a standalone app with py2app?

Tags: python, tkinter, py2app, python-standalone

I have built a simple python app with Tkinker, which has a super small sqlite file with it. The app is here, https://github.com/yts61/bookstore_app.git

Having failed in pyinstaller many times, i am turing to py2app in the hope to make one standalone app file which i can share around. I googled and followed this youtube tutorial,

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=u4ykDbciXa8, and again failed the mission. My setup.py file is like the one below,

```
from setuptools import setup
    APP = ['frontend.py']
    DATA_FILES = ['books.db','backend.py']
    OPTIONS = {
        'iconfile':'favicon.ico',
        'argv_emulation': True,
        'packages': ['certifi'],
        }
    setup(
        app=APP,
        data_files=DATA_FILES,
        options={'py2app': OPTIONS},
        setup_requires=['py2app'],
)
```

In the terminal, i tried `python setup.py py2app -A`, and clicked the frontend file in `Content/MacOS/frontend` to test run the app as suggested by the tutorial, however, the app won't run, and my Mac flashed and reset itself.

Would anyone please help ?
I have asked another question about building this standalone app with pyinstaller.
[What is the proper way to use pyinstaller on Mac?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63560528/what-is-the-proper-way-to-use-pyinstaller-on-mac)

Comment: I have never used PyInstaller or py2app, I find I prefer to write up a C++ program to check if Python is installed, and if it isn't, install it, then download and run the program. I could submit this as an answer if you like but it's too big to fit in a comment.

Comment: Building exes from python scripts is very finiky. you might need to add hooks, or take a look at pyinstallers trouble shooting guide as they have a thorough list of solutions to common problems.